# How next.config.js sets up environment variables?

Tags: node.js, next.js

NexJs is completely new framework for me and I've been studying it.

I'm following [this](https://youtu.be/tt9hws5JGRc?t=688) video tutorial and one of the steps is to create a file **next.config.js**.
In this file I put:

```
module.exports ={
    env: {
        MONGO_URI: "mongodb+srv://username:pwd@cluster0.yxxxx.mongodb.net/ricoapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    }
}
```

And later I connect to mongo db like this:

```
console.log('1: ', Object.keys(process.env).includes("MONGO_URI"));
console.log('2: ', "MONGO_URI" in process.env);
console.log('3: ', typeof process.env.MONGO_URI);
console.log('4: ', Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(process.env));
console.log('5: ',process.env.MONGO_URI);
const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

In the console I get the following output:

> 1:  false

> 2:  false

> 3:  string

> 4:  []

> 5: mongodb+srv://username:pwd@cluster0.yxxxx.mongodb.net/ricoapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority

So the `MONGO_URI` is somehow available trough `process.env.MONGO_URI` but is it seems to me not a property of `process.env`.

What am I missing here? This doesnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables defined in `next.config.js` are replaced before the server starts. So every occurrence of `process.env.MONGO_URI` will be replaced with the string value you defined in `next.config.js`.

### Example

Let's say you have a config like this:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports ={
    env: {
        MY_ENV_VAR: "value_of_my_env_var"
    }
}
```

And Next.js API function like this:

```js
// pages/api/index.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const response = process.env.MY_ENV_VAR;

  res.statusCode = 200
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.end(response)
}
```

After running `npm run dev` or `npm run build` the code is compiled by webpack to this:

```js
// pages/api/index.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const response =  "value_of_my_env_var";

  res.statusCode = 200
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.end(response)
}
```

---

From the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables):

> Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with 'my-value' at build time. Trying to destructure process.env variables won't work due to the nature of webpack DefinePlugin.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.
But how do we manage multiple environments (for example "development", "stage", "production")? Something like `$ NODE_ENV=production npm start`

Comment: It depends based on your deployment: If you build a static site (HTML+CSS) you can always access `process.env` in the `next.config.js` at build time. So you could set the value of an env var based on your NODE_ENV: `{ MY_ENV_VAR: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'prod' : 'dev' }`.

Comment: If you run Next.js as a server (and don't want to have multiple builds based on your environment) you can remove the dynamic env vars from `next.config.js` altogether. You then have to make sure that the environment (e.g. a docker container) has set the env vars and then you can access them with `process.env.XXX`. But this only works on code parts that are server side (e.g. API routes or in `getServerSideProps`).